# Insert xml into MySql using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, xml

I am trying to import xml data into a mysql table. I have the below fields to be Imported:

reference

price

category

type

city

property

imgurl1

imgurl2

The problem is that the number of `<imgurl>(url to image file)` is not the same. Below is the code:

```
$conn = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password);
if(! $conn )
{
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db($dbname,$conn) or die( mysql_error() );

$xml = simplexml_load_file('http://astonpearlemail.net/feeds/feedsmall.xml');
$data = $fields = array();
foreach ($xml->xpath('listing') as $listing) {
$fields = array_keys((array)($listing));
$data[] = '("' . join('", "', (array)$listing) . '")';
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO ap_prop (" . join(', ', $fields) . ") VALUES\n" ;
$sql .= join (",\n", $data);
$result1 = mysql_query($sql,$conn);
echo "<pre>$sql</pre>"
```

Please suggest how I can import the varying number of `imgurl`.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Number of image url is not the same MEANS?...can you explain more?

Comment: do you want to create a table out of the elements or do you want the whole xml file stored? You can use text, long text, or blob to store it in a column.

Comment: Hi Vishal: The xml file has property details, so for some property there maybe 3 photos so in this case the xml will have something like below:
<imgurl-1>url of photo</imgurl-1>
<imgurl-2>url of photo</imgurl-2>
<imgurl-3>url of photo</imgurl-3>
For other property there maybe 2 photos so the XML will be like below
<imgurl-1>url of photo</imgurl-1>
<imgurl-2>url of photo</imgurl-2>
So there are different number of <imgurl> tags for each record.
Hope I am able to explain the situation.

Comment: I already have a table with and I want to insert from each xml node to Table fileds